# User input validation Bootstrap 4 and JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-validate

I started learning Bootstrap 4 validation and there are few things that are not clear to me. Some of the situations are confusing in case where input fields that are not required are showing `valid-feedback` / `invalid-feedback`. Also, I'm wondering if there is a way to trigger validation with button on click instead of submit process? Here is example of what I have so far:

```js
// Example starter JavaScript for disabling form submissions if there are invalid fields
(function() {
  'use strict';
  window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    // Fetch all the forms we want to apply custom Bootstrap validation styles to
    var forms = document.getElementsByClassName('needs-validation');
    // Loop over them and prevent submission
    var validation = Array.prototype.filter.call(forms, function(form) {
      form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
        if (form.checkValidity() === false) {
          event.preventDefault();
          event.stopPropagation();
        }

        form.classList.add('was-validated');
      }, false);
    });
  }, false);
})();
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<div class="container">
  <fieldset class="fieldset-info">
    <legend class="hcs-legend">Add New Profile</legend>
    <form name="new-profile" id="new-profile" class="needs-validation" novalidate>

      <div class="form-group required">
        <label for="agency">Profile Name:</label>
        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="profile" id="profile" value="" maxlength="120" placeholder="Enter the official name of your profile" required>
        <div class="invalid-feedback">Please provide Profile Name</div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group required">
        <label>Type:</label>
        <select class="custom-select browser-default" name="type" id="type" required>
          <option value="">--Select Type--</option>
          <option value="1">Large</option>
          <option value="2">Medium</option>
          <option value="3">Small</option>
        </select>
        <div class="invalid-feedback">Please provide Type</div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group row required">
        <label class="col-2 col-form-label" for="fname">First Name:</label>
        <div class="col-10">
          <input class="form-control" type="text" name="fname" id="fname" value="" maxlength="20" placeholder="Enter First name" required>
          <div class="invalid-feedback">Please provide First Name</div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group row">
        <label class="col-2 col-form-label" for="middle_ini">Middle Init:</label>
        <div class="col-10">
          <input class="form-control" type="text" name="middle_ini" id="middle_ini" value="" maxlength="1" placeholder="Enter Middle Initial (optional).">
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group row required">
        <label class="col-2 col-form-label" for="lname">Last Name:</label>
        <div class="col-10">
          <input class="form-control" type="text" name="lname" id="lname" value="" maxlength="30" placeholder="Enter Last name" required>
          <div class="invalid-feedback">Please provide Last Name</div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group row required">
        <label class="col-2 col-form-label" for="email">Email:</label>
        <div class="col-10">
          <input class="form-control" type="text" name="email" id="email" value="" maxlength="50" placeholder="Enter Email" required>
          <div class="invalid-feedback">Please provide Email</div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12"><strong><u>Physical Address</u></strong></div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-row">
        <div class="form-group col-6 required">
          <div class="row">
            <label class="col-3 col-form-label" for="Addr1">Address 1:</label>
            <div class="col-9">
              <input class="form-control" type="text" name="Addr1" id="Addr1" value="" placeholder="Enter Physical Address 1" maxlength="40" required>
              <div class="invalid-feedback">Please provide Address 1</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-6 required">
          <div class="row">
            <label class="col-2 col-form-label" for="city">City:</label>
            <div class="col-10">
              <input class="form-control" type="text" name="city" id="city" value="" placeholder="Enter City" maxlength="25" required>
              <div class="invalid-feedback">Please provide City</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-row">
        <div class="form-group col-6">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-3">
              <label for="Addr2">Address 2:</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-9">
              <input class="form-control" type="text" name="Addr2" id="Addr2" value="" placeholder="Enter Physical Address 2" maxlength="40">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-6 required">
          <div class="row">
            <label class="col-2 col-form-label" for="state">State:</label>
            <div class="col-10">
              <select class="custom-select browser-default" name="state" id="state" required>
                <option value="">--Select State--</option>
                <option value="ny">New York</option>
                <option value="fl">Florida</option>

              </select>
              <div class="invalid-feedback">Please provide State</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-row">
        <div class="form-group col-6">
          <div class="row">
            <label class="col-3 col-form-label" for="Addr3">Address 3:</label>
            <div class="col-9">
              <input class="form-control" type="text" name="Addr3" id="Addr3" value="" placeholder="Enter Physical Address 3" maxlength="40">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-6 required">
          <div class="row">
            <label class="col-2 col-form-label" for="zip">Zip:</label>
            <div class="col-10">
              <input class="form-control" type="text" name="zip" id="zip" value="" placeholder="Enter Zip Code, formatted: 99999 or 99999-9999" maxlength="10" required>
              <div class="invalid-feedback">Please provide Zip</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-row">
        <div class="form-group col-6">
          <div class="row">
            <label class="col-3 col-form-label" for="Addr4">Address 4:</label>
            <div class="col-9">
              <input class="form-control" type="text" name="Addr4" id="Addr4" value="" placeholder="Enter Physical Address 4" maxlength="40">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-6">
          <div class="form-check">
            <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="sameAddress" id="sameAddress" value="Y">
            <label class="form-check-label" for="sameAddress">check this box if mailing address is the same of physical address</label>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12"><strong><u>Access options</u></strong></div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-check">
        <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="flag_1" id="flag_1" value="Y">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="flag_1">Allow for access level 1?</label>
      </div>
      <div class="form-check">
        <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="flag_2" id="flag_2" value="Y">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="flag_2">Allow for access level 2?</label>
      </div>
      <div class="form-check">
        <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="flag_3" id="flag_3" value="Y">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="flag_3">Allow for access level 3?</label>
      </div>

      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12 text-center">
          <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="save" id="save" value="Save">
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </fieldset>
</div>
```

In the example above I used the code for validation form the Bootstrap web site. There is very little explained on how this works. I have few questions:

1. How I can trigger validation on click since I will use ajax to send request to the server?
2. Why fields that are not required are turning green (color around the input)?
3. How I can use pattern attribute to validate input value if it's correct or not with custom message for the user?

Please let me know if anyone knows how to achieve this?

Thank you.

Comment: Off the bat, I'd say if they're not required and they're not filled out, they'll turn green because they are valid.

Comment: @zfrisch What about sending ajax request and triggering validation manually? Also, do you know if pattern attribute is working with bootstrap validation?

Comment: I don't know what you mean? You are triggering validation on click . It automatically matches the pattern for validity. What does that have to do with manual AJAX?

Comment: @zfrisch Ok, let me ask you this. How you would send the ajax request with the current code?